# Finding Radio Button using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to make fill a feedback form ( actually it is attendance ) automatically with python. I'm able to traverse through all the pages but every page has different value and id for "Present" it is kind of dynamic

Is there a way I can find "Present" radio button on the page. I don't have much knowledge of html

[image: snippets of the website]

P.S. I've read the question on stackoverflow already but the answer were not able to solve it will still give me error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Present** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *index*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='statusdesc' and text()='Present']//preceding::input[1]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *attributes*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='statusdesc' and text()='Present']//preceding::input[@class='form-check-input ' and @name='status']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 2):

This xpath should find your input tag based off the Present tag.

```
//span[text()='Present']/preceding::input
```

By it's class

```
//input[class='form-check-input ']
```